# Inference using partial longitudinal data

Tags: regression

Suppose two groups of people from country A and country B responded to a question before an event. Sometime after the event again two groups from the same countries responded to that question. Now let's assume 50% of the respondents are shared between the two waves in both countries. We don't know whether the samples are representative of the population of the countries but we still want to learn something about the country specific effect of the event. Suppose this is the summary of the data:

| Country | Wave 1 (YES rate) | Wave 2 (YES rate) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.3 | 0.5 |
| B | 0.4 | 0.7 |

Can we estimate the country specific effects using the following model ignoring the fact that 50% of the participants are shared within countries between wave 1 & 2?

$y_{icw} \sim Bernoulli(\lambda_{cw})$

where $y_{icw}$ is the response of the participant $i$ at country $c$ and wave $w$. And $\lambda_{cw}$ is the country specific effect in wave $w$.